# Poisson Equation on an unbounded domain with fast decay

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, poissons-equation

Some text books on PDE (Evans, Gilbarg and Trudinger for instance) give a solution to Poisson's equation $-\Delta u = f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x - y)f(y)\; dy$, where $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution, and where $f$ is $C^2$ with compact support.

I think I've heard somewhere that $f$ having compact support is not necessary, only that $f$ decay fast enough in some sense at infinity.

My question is: does any one have a precise statement of this, or a reference?

For instance, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, would this
$$
|D_{ij}f(x)| \leq \frac{C}{(1 + |x|^2|)^2},
$$
for some constant $C$, be sufficiently fast decay to ensure that $-\Delta u = f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ even if $f$ does not have compact support?

Thank you for your advice!

EDIT: Or I am mistaken and compact support is necessary?

Comment: Well, you at least need $\Phi(x-y)f(y)$ to be integrable. Since $\Phi(x)\sim |x|^{2-n}$ ($n\geq 3)$ you need $|f(x)|\leq 1/(1+|x|^p)$ for $p>2$. To get that $u\in C^2$, you need to be able to differentiate $f$ under the integral, so one would expect that $\Phi(x-y)D^2f(y)$ should be integrable. Your condition seems more than sufficient. You should be able to follow the proof in Evans with minor modifications, where do you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you for the comment Jeff, this is very helpful. After looking at Evans' proof again,  I see where the modification would need to be. (If I understand correctly, that $f$ has compact support is used only to know that $|| Df ||_{\infty} <\infty$ ). This is part of a longer computation, and am hopeful that there is a reference I could cite rather than reproduce Evans' proof with modification. Do you know of such a reference?